# JSON is a transport protocol like SOAP or format language like XML

Tags: xml, json, soap

Just want to clear my logic on JSON, it is a transport protocol like SOAP or a markup language like XML? why i am asking this question because when  start searching soap content there are lots of links available where both the comparison JSON/SOAP and JSON/XML exists.

Thanks,
A agg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it is a transport protocol like SOAP or a markup language like XML?

No. It is a data format (like XML) but not a markup language.

Comment: Sorry for using wrong words here , but again if its like xml then how one can compare it with SOAP?

Comment: I guess a lot of people just use SOAP as a horribly complex box to squirt small pieces of data about the place. It is probably better to compare REST+JSON to SOAP (at least if you are going to use SOAP properly).

Comment: Thanks for your answer so if JSON is data format like XML . can i use JSON with SOAP instead of XML?

Comment: SOAP is based around XML. You could probably encode a JSON text as a textNode in the SOAP XML document if you really wanted. TBH, I'd avoid SOAP altogether. Everything I have heard about it suggests that it is a huge bundle of complexity that solves some very rare edge cases I'll never need to worry about. REST makes much more sense to me.